# Setting Training + Testing Set based on observation number

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

Pretty new to pandas, and I have been utilizing a lot of the given packages in Python to fit a regression model.

I currently have 3 months of data, and I would like to split up the training set to encompass observations 0 to 40 because it covers the first 2 months of my data, and I would like to use the last month of the data as a test set.

Before, I was using

`X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.33, random state = 42)`

as the foundation for the model, but I don't want my sampling randomized.

So, my question is, how do I index my  data frame so the training sets cover observations 0-40, and the test set covers 40-71?

Any feedback is appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you need.  Note that you specified that 40 be in both sets.  I assumed you didn't want that but if you do, you can adjust.

```
X_train = X.iloc[0:40]  # doesn't include 40 
X_test = X.iloc[40:72]  # doesn't include 72
y_train = y.iloc[0:40]  # doesn't include 40
y_test = y.iloc[40:72]  # doesn't include 72
```